# URL query on VF page that contains a lightning component

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components

I have a visualforce page that contains a lightning component. I am wanting to put the VF page in a custom Lightning Page Tab (app home template) and pass a url parameter to the Lightning Component that's inside the VF page. I have tried just about everything and can not seem to get it to happen. Can someone please help??

```
{!$CurrentPage.parameters.recordId}

{!$CurrentPage.parameters.id}

{!$CurrentPage.parameters.parameter_id}
```

This is what i have tried inside the visualforce page to test to see if the VF page is grabbing anything from the URL but its not

My URL

> https://rainsoftse.lightning.force.com/lightning/n/Service?0.blue=0WO1Q000000zNXyWAM&0.id=0WO1Q000000zNXyWAM0.recordId=0WO1Q000000zNXyWAM

```
<apex:page >

<apex:includeLightning />

**{!$CurrentPage.parameters.recordId}

{!$CurrentPage.parameters.id}

{!$CurrentPage.parameters.parameter_id}**

<div id="LcDisplayId"></div> 

<span>url Id {!$CurrentPage.parameters.blue}</span>

   <script>

      // Here 'VfApp' Is Lightning Application Name
    $Lightning.use("c:AssetDetailTileApp", function() {
      /* 'LcForVf' is Lightning Component Name which we are Displaying In Vf Page 
       * syntax for create lightning component dynamically :
       * $Lightning.createComponent(String type, Object attributes, String locator, function callback) */

    $Lightning.createComponent("c:AllAssetDetailTile",
    { 
      // Set Lightning Component Attributes Property before creating Lightning Component In Visualforce page 
        recordId : '{!$CurrentPage.parameters.Id}' 
    },   


   "LcDisplayId",
    function(component) {
        // create component Callback, Lightning Component has been Created,
        // Now you can set more lightning Component attributes here,
        // and do more cool stuff here
        component.set("v.recordId" , '{!$CurrentPage.parameters.Id}');
    });
 });
 </script>


<script>
      // Here 'VfApp' Is Lightning Application Name
    $Lightning.use("c:AssetDetailTileApp", function() {
      /* 'LcForVf' is Lightning Component Name which we are Displaying In Vf Page 
       * syntax for create lightning component dynamically :
       * $Lightning.createComponent(String type, Object attributes, String locator, function callback) */

    $Lightning.createComponent("c:AllAssetSideTab",
    { 
      // Set Lightning Component Attributes Property before creating Lightning Component In Visualforce page 
        recordId : '{!$CurrentPage.parameters.Id}' 
    },   


   "LcDisplayId",
    function(component) {
        // create component Callback, Lightning Component has been Created,
        // Now you can set more lightning Component attributes here,
        // and do more cool stuff here
        component.set("v.recordId" , '{!$CurrentPage.parameters.id}');
    });
 });


 </script>

</apex:page>
```

Comment: this look slike copy pasted code - where exactly in it are you facing an issue? I can suggest you go through [Communicating between Lightning Components and Visualforce Pages](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2017/01/lightning-visualforce-communication.html)

Comment: i can not get the visualforce page to get the parameter from the url

Comment: As is, it looks like you copy pasted code from a blog and asking for 'how to do x' without providing details as to what it is you have t ried, or where you are stuck. please read [ask] and take the [tour] in order to get a better understanding of how this site works.

Comment: I have a visualforce page that contains a lightning component. I am wanting to put the VF page in a custom Lightning Page Tab (app home template) and pass a url parameter to the Lightning Component that's inside the VF page. I have tried just about everything and can not seem to get it to happen. Can someone please help??<------ that is in my question that's where I'm stuck i have tried everything to get the URL parameter to the viusalforce page that has an embedded Lightning Component.

Comment: what is your currentpage parameter returning? null, empty string? any debugging? have you tried getting the parameter in your lighting component on initialization? have you tried assigning the currentpage parameter to a variable before assinging it to an attribute?

Comment: What's the design purpose behind embedding a Lightning Out Visualforce page containing a Lightning component within a native Lightning application container? If you can surface the component directly within the app page, you will save yourself a lot of headaches.

Comment: The *proximate* answer to your question, which is not very useful, is that your URL does not contain parameters `id`, `recordId`, or `parameter_id`. It contains parameters `0.blue` and `0.recordId`, although a suspect another `&` got lost in the journey to this question.

Comment: We use Field Service Lightning and the only way to pass a url parameter in is a lightning page extension to the Salesforce1 app. I have tried to put just the component into the Lightning Page but it isn't getting the URL so someone told me to put it inside a visualforce page that VF pages can get a URL parameter and pass it to the lightning component.

Comment: Its not returning anything just blank. @glls